# javascript: how to use javascript array in for loop

Tags: javascript

I am new to working in js so that my code is not working

my code is:

```
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let addfruit;
let fruitList = [];
let howManyTimes = prompt("how many fruit to want to add?");
for (let index = 0; index < howManyTimes.length; index++) {
       addfruit = prompt("enter fruits name");
    if (addfruit == "no") {
        break;
    }
  fruitList.push(addfruit);
}
for (myShop of fruitList) {
    output.innerHTML += myShop + "<br/>";
}
```

my problem is that there is when I want 5 times prompt then I will get only 1 prompt

any help thanks.

Comment: Javascript is asynchronous so loop will not wait for prompt to close

Comment: you will consider howManyTimes as array but it is variable

Comment: @Ajith Agree with you. You can read more about async JS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: @Ajith: That's not true. Of course the loop will wait. If a prompt was async, it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping: Nothing in the code above will run asynchronously; the info in that link won't apply here.

Comment: @Ajith `prompt`, `alert`, `confirm` are thread blocking.

Comment: @adiga Well I understood.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be used that.

```
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let addfruit;
let fruitList = [];
let howManyTimes = prompt("how many fruit to want to add?");
for (let index = 0; index < howManyTimes; index++) {

    addfruit = prompt("enter fruits name");
    if (addfruit == "no") {
        break;
    }
    fruitList.push(addfruit);
}
for (myShop of fruitList) {
    output.innerHTML += myShop + "<br/>";
}
```

you will run this

Answer (score 2):

`howManyTimes` is a string, not an array.

You need to convert it to number and then use it in loop condition

```
let howManyTimes = Number(prompt("how many fruit to want to add?"));
```

You can also rely on javascript's type coercion to convert `howManyTimes` to a number. So you can skip explicitly converting `howManyTimes` to a number.

```
for (let index = 0; index < howManyTimes; index++) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have use `.length` .length can be used for `arrays`

Do something like that

Run Snippet to see it work.

```js
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let addfruit;
let fruitList = [];
let howManyTimes = prompt("how many fruit to want to add?");
for (let index = 0; index < howManyTimes; index++) {
  addfruit = prompt("enter fruits name");
  if (addfruit == "no") {
    break;
  }
  fruitList.push(addfruit);
}
for (myShop of fruitList) {
  output.innerHTML += myShop + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removing '.length' property in the input howManyTimes works,

```
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let addfruit;
let fruitList = [];
let howManyTimes = prompt("how many fruit to want to add?");
for (let index = 0; index < howManyTimes; index++) {
       addfruit = prompt("enter fruits name");
    if (addfruit == "no") {
        break;
    }
  fruitList.push(addfruit); 
   
}
for (myShop of fruitList) {
    output.innerHTML += myShop + "<br/>";
}
```